# RTSP gstreamer pipepline to Android VideoView

Tags: android, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to construct a gstreamer pipeline on a Panda to RTSP video+audio to Android 4.1.2 app.  The Android app uses:

```
videoView.setVideoURL(Uri.parse(":rtsp://..."))
```

to view the video.  On the Panda I've built gstreamer-0.10 (to get a working uvch264_src element to take H.264 video from a Logitech C920 camera) and  using gst-rtsp-server/exmaples/test-launch to serve up video+audio via:

```
./test-launch 'uvch264_src do-timestamp=true mode=2 post-previews=false usage-type=1 iframe-period=2000 peak-bitrate=400000 rate-control=qp auto-start=true name=src ! queue ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1,profile=constrained-baseline ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 \
alsasrc do-timestamp=true device=plughw:2,0 ! audio/x-raw-int,rate=44100 ! queue ! audioconvert ! ffenc_ac3 ! rtpac3pay name=pay1 pt=97'
```

I can view the stream on VLC (audio isn't in sync), but the Android tablet fails to play the stream.  If I remove the audio portion of the pipeline:

```
./test-launch 'uvch264_src do-timestamp=true mode=2 post-previews=false usage-type=1 iframe-period=2000 peak-bitrate=400000 rate-control=qp auto-start=true name=src ! queue ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1,profile=constrained-baseline ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96'
```

Then the Android app has no problem playing it.

How can I encode the audio+video pipeline such that videoView can play it?
Do I need to mux the audio and video together into a MPEG-TS stream first?

Comment: Solved; using the following pipeline: `./test-launch 'uvch264_src do-timestamp=true mode=2 post-previews=false usage-type=1 iframe-period=2000 peak-bitrate=400000 rate-control=qp auto-start=true name=src ! queue ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1,profile=constrained-baseline ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 alsasrc do-timestamp=true device=plughw:2,0 ! audio/x-raw-int,rate=44100 ! queue ! audioconvert ! ffenc_aac ! rtpmp4apay name=pay1 pt=97'` I can view 1080p video and 44.1kHz audio concurrently via viewVideo() on an Android tablet.